# Significantly different in categorical variables

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I am working with a categorical variable with 4 mutually exclusive classifications (CC, CD, DC and DD). I had counted how many times each classification is repeated. (for example, 33 CC, 40 CD, 50 DC and 100 DD). I would like to know if there are a significant difference between them, and between which of them.
I am doing this with Matlab

Comment: Significantly different what? Total count / frequency / proportion?

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in testing against a null hypothesis that the counts across categories are equal.  But there's not enough information in the question to be sure. In this case, you might look at chi-square goodness-of-fit test, standardized residuals from a chi-square goodness-of-fit test, and Sison and Glaz multinomial confidence intervals.

Comment: Exactly, my idea is to compare if the total count of one category is significantly different from another.

Comment: I am not sure why Chi-square goodness-of-fit test could be use in this situation. I haven't got a model to fit. Or am I confused?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to test if "there are equal counts". That must be reformulated to "equal *expected* counts" to be a valid hypothesis. That *is* a model, namely, an equal probability model on 4 different levels of a categorical variable (in R a categorical variable is named a *factor*,) I do not know about matlab.

There is not enough information in your post for a full answer, I will assume independent sampling, otherwise we cannot advance ... So in R I will do, it should be possible in matlab:

```
 (tab  <-  as.table(c("CC"=33, "CD"=40, "DC"=50, "DD"=100))  )
 CC  CD  DC  DD 
 33  40  50 100 
  chisq.test(tab)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  tab
X-squared = 49.448, df = 3, p-value = 1.047e-10
```

The test above assumes by default equal probabilities, otherwise null probabilities can be given via an argument `p=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)`, say.