# Chi-square goodness-of-fit test

Tags: statistical-significance

I am working with a categorical variable with 4 mutually exclusive classifications (CC, CD, DC and DD). I had counted how many times each classification is repeated. (for example, 33 CC, 40 CD, 50 DC and 100 DD). I would like to know if there are a significant difference between the total count of them, and between which total count of them.
The null hypothesis could be that all the categories are equally probable.

Comment: Yeah, the null hypothesis could be that. But first of all: what is your question exactly?

Comment: related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/393070/significantly-different-in-categorical-variables

Answer (score 1):

A Chi-square test could be used, although you can already see that the group with 100 observations is clearly sticking out. The null hypothesis of the test is that no relationship exists in the categorical variables in the population; they are independent.

```
> chisq.test(c(33,40,50,100))

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(33, 40, 50, 100)
X-squared = 49.448, df = 3, p-value = 1.047e-10
```

We can clearly reject that ($p<0.001$). As for a test for each pair, this will be harder, you could use a plot.

Comment: The null hypothesis is of independence and equal probabilities here. It's perfectly possible to have independence and unequal probabilities.